# Missing exponentiation magic method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm defining a bunch of numerical magic methods in a custom class and have found a gap I can't explain, relating to `pow()` / exponentiation.

`__pow__(self, other, modulo=None)` is called when your custom class is the first / leftmost operand.

`__rpow__(self, other, modulo=None)` is called when your custom class is the second operand.

I've found a case where neither are called, and I don't get it. Here's an example case that simply returns the name of the method being called:

```
class Power:
    def __pow__(self, other, modulo=None):
        return '__pow__'
    def __rpow__(self, other, modulo=None):
        return '__rpow__'

>>> x = Power()
>>> pow(x, 5)
'__pow__'
>>> pow(5, x)
'__rpow__'
```

So far, looks right. But look what happens when you use the optional modulo argument:

```
>>> pow(x, x, 5)
'__pow__'
>>> pow(5, x, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'int', 'Power', 'int'
```

tl;dr it seems `__rpow__` doesn't get called when using the modulo argument. What gives?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is documented. There's no easy way for Python to make this work with 3 operands. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rpow__

Comment: @blubberdiblub Thanks for the link! It's unclear to me what _is_ getting called in this case. Is it just going straight to the C implementation with no way to override it?

Comment: Well, it should be calling the `__pow__()` of the first operand in this case, which is the `int` 5. So yes, it should be going to the built-in implementation of `pow` for numbers. The second operand will then likely have to be compatible with `int`, `float` or `complex`. For simplicity, it's probably best to ignore the third operand to `pow`, unless you're writing performance critical code for cryptography or mathematics, which is what this special case third operand was designed for, if I'm not mistaken. But then you have a special case application anyway.

Comment: Thanks @blubberdiblub. FWIW you've basically given the answer, if you want to reformat both your comments into an answer I'll accept it.